# Installing Adobe Pro and Adobe Reader on the same machine

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, pdf-reader, pdfcreator

We have multiple users working on a terminal servers

A few have license for Adobe Pro

The rest of the users need access to the 'regular' Adobe Reader that does not require a license.

Tried installing Adobe Pro on the terminal server -

it uninstalled and canceled out Adobe Reader.

We need a way to keep both versions on the same machine

Major problem with Adobe Pro is - It wouldn't let users use reading functionality without logging in with an email address that has a license attatched to it.

It just force quits, leaving reading PDF files impossible for users without Adobe Pro license.

How can we keep both versions?

Or, is there a way to tell Adove Pro not to force quit while not in 'logged in' mode and keep reading functionality?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the post
[How can I install Acrobat Pro and Reader on same device?](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/how-can-i-install-acrobat-pro-and-reader-on-same-device/td-p/12747538)
one user did it this way:

> I was actually able to get around it by uninstalling Pro, downloading and installing Reader, then re-installing Pro.

But as the Adobe documentation says, it's now possible to install
them both by using the
[64-bit Unified App Installer](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DesktopDeployment/singleinstaller.html#bit-unified-app-installer),
described as:

> To streamline installs and simplify app management for large enterprise, Adobe now delivers a 64-bit Acrobat and Reader all-language (MUI) unified installer. Adobe’s single-app initiative provides both Acrobat and Reader functionality via a single installer, a common default install location, and a common executable and registry hive.

This installation is 64-bit and requires that the 32-bit Reader
be uninstalled (if already installed).

Comment: Thank you for the answer sadly however both methods did not work. Installing Reader then Pro leads to Reader override by Pro. Installing Pro then Reader leads to an error message 'adobe reader already installed'

Comment: Does that happen with the Unified Installer?